# How to draw a vertical line of desired length in equations.

Tags: math-mode, symbols, rules

I am writing a big formula where a vertical line is needed. Instead of `$\vline$` or `$|$`, does anyone know a way to draw this vertical line of desired length? The formula is something like

```
$$
E\Bigg[
F_{m-1}\Big( \text{some big contents} \Big) |\: \mathcal{F}_1
\Bigg]
$$
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: For lots of examples and techniques for typesetting math, the `mathmode` documentation is very helpful.  It should be part of your TeX distribution.

Comment: Thanks Alan Munn, I guess what you mean is this one: http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf  It is very helpful.:-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, if you are manually defining the size, as in the example you could just put a `\Bigg|` at the right place. Probably better would be using `\left`, `\middle` and `\right`.

By the way: You should prefer `\[` and `\]` instead of double `$$`.

```
\[ E\left[ F_{m-1}\Big( \text{some big contents} \Big) \middle|\: \mathcal{F}_1 \right] \]
```

Comment: just curious, why should we prefer \[ to $$ ?

Answer (score 39):

Try enclosing your expression into `\left.` and `\right\vert`, as in

```
\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial\bm{\beta}}\right\vert_{\hat\beta}=-2\bm{X'y}+2\bm{X'X\hat\beta}=0
```

which yields:

[image]

Comment: Note that there is a dot in `\left.`. I wondered for a while why it didn't work.

Comment: You tricky tricky you.