# How can I tweak the length of the \left \right vertical lines of the cardinality of a displaystyle \bigcup?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

$$\left| \bigcup_{\substack{V \subseteq C_m \\ V \supsetneq U}} \mathcal{B}_V \right|$$

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

which looks imbalanced as the vertical lines are much longer at the top than the bottom.  How can I tweak this to make it look nicer?

Changing the `\left` and `\right` to `\Big` gives the following, but it's also not great:

[image]

Changing to `\left\vert` and `\right\vert` (as per [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8138/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-of-desired-length-in-equations)) is also poor:

[image]

Comment: `\biggl|` and `\biggr|` should be enough.

Comment: I'd say `\Bigl/Bigr` is enough here. It is clear what they fence in, and they do not dominate the expression.

Comment: Also note: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to (`$$...$$` is not LaTeX)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please observe `\Bigl` ... `\Bigr`, not `\Big` ... `\Big` pair and `\[` ... `\]`, not `$$` ... `$$`.  You can choose more convenient vertical dimension from the suggested ones, however your second example looks pretty good.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

%    $$\left| 
\[
\Bigl\biggl\Biggl|\bigcup_{\substack{V \subseteq C_m \\ V \supsetneq U}} \mathcal{B}_V 
\Bigr\biggr\Biggr|
\]
%\right|$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  \Biggl| and \Biggr| is my favourite, so I'll use that.

Answer (score 5):

Delimiters are not required to cover the whole subformula, so `\bigg` or `\Bigg` might do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

Wrong:
\[
\left| \bigcup_{\substack{V \subseteq C_m \\ V \supsetneq U}} \mathcal{B}_V \right|
\]
Possibly right:
\[
\biggl| \bigcup_{\substack{V \subseteq C_m \\ V \supsetneq U}} \mathcal{B}_V \biggr|
\qquad
\Biggl| \bigcup_{\substack{V \subseteq C_m \\ V \supsetneq U}} \mathcal{B}_V \Biggr|
\]
Easier
\[
\abs[\bigg]{\bigcup_{\substack{V \subseteq C_m \\ V \supsetneq U}} \mathcal{B}_V}
\qquad
\abs[\Bigg]{\bigcup_{\substack{V \subseteq C_m \\ V \supsetneq U}} \mathcal{B}_V}
\]
Overkill:
\[
\raisebox{-1.5ex}{%
  $\abs[\Bigg]{%
    \raisebox{1.5ex}{%
      $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\substack{V \subseteq C_m \\ V \supsetneq U}} \mathcal{B}_V$%
    }%
  }$%
}
=3
\]
\end{document}
```

Take your pick. I wouldn't choose the last one; personally, I'd go with `\bigg`.

[image]